# how to create a group chat

Tags: android, chat

I want to create Group Chat application in which groups would be predefined on basis of some quality
eg. basis of department in case of employee
a group would be created on basis of department and all the members having same department would be added automatically
now if any one posts here any thing it should be broadcasted to all members of that group.
please help me how to create such app
I have succeeded in creating the one - one chat app in same app I want to integrate this facility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use SignalA api for client application and for server you can use WebSocket ,
if you are using Microsoft .Net platform in server, then you can use ASP.NET SignalR

https://github.com/erizet/SignalA

http://signalr.net/

https://github.com/SignalR/java-samples

Java server api for supporting SignalR

https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere

Answer (score 0):

In android you can use xmpp or socket.

i think xmpp is better.

http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/